# What is the issue with the trailing comma of JSON Object

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Usually i am creating valid JSON objects like this:

```
{
  hasPermission: true,
  notificationStatusId: 1
};
```

ON VSCode, when is save the file, sometimes it's adding a tailing comma automatically after the last property like this:

```
{
  hasPermission: true,
  notificationStatusId: 1,
};
```

Actually I'm **not** asking how to disable that behavior and i know how to do that. i am asking what is the reason VSCode has that feature of adding a trailing comma automatically?

Comment: That's *not* JSON, where a trailing comma would be a problem, it's JS. Presumably something (Prettier or some other linter) is configured to format on save.

Comment: It's valid [JSON5](https://json5.org)

Comment: Oh but there's a that trailing semicolon too... which isn't valid json anything (and this is also not even valid js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing comma is probably added by [prettier](https://prettier.io/) code formatter. This is recommended for javascript, and disallowed for JSON according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas):

> Trailing commas (sometimes called "final commas") can
> be useful when adding new elements, parameters, or properties to
> JavaScript code. If you want to add a new property, you can add a new
> line without modifying the previously last line if that line already
> uses a trailing comma. This makes version-control diffs cleaner and
> editing code might be less troublesome.
>
> JavaScript has allowed trailing commas in array literals since the
> beginning, and later added them to object literals (ECMAScript 5) and
> most recently (ECMAScript 2017) to function parameters.
>
> JSON, however, disallows trailing commas.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure the file's [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) is set to just `JSON` (not `JSON with comments` or `JSON5` or `JSON takes Manhattan`). The 
language mode is displayed in the lower right corner of the status bar:

[image: JSON language mode]

VS Code will warn you about trailing commands in the `JSON` language mode.

As for why the trailing comma is being inserted, that is likely caused by one of your extensions as VS Code should not do this by default. Try going through your extensions to identify which one is causing this

Answer (score 4):

If you are using some linter like prettier, Recently Default value of Trailing commas changed from **"none"** to **"es5"** in new versions
To fix this you have to change configuration of your linter
In case of prettier, create a file ***.prettierrc.json*** with content

```
{"trailingComma": "none"}
```